# Manipulating Results After API Call and JSON.parse

Tags: json, ruby

Using Ruby, I am pulling from an API into response, and then parsing using JSON.parse into result

```
result = JSON.parse(response)
```

In the get, there is extra "metadata" and "data", as well as the actual "items" being outputted

the output looks similar to this:

> {"metadata"=>{"version"=>5}, "data"=>{"paging"=>{"total_items"=>1, "number_of_pages"=>1}, "items"=>[{"type"=>"OrganizationSummary", "uid"=>"33a97e", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Google"}]

I want to remove the "metadata", and "data," from result, and output the uid (33a97e) and name (Google) of the pulled items.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One, the `result` hash you posted in question has syntax error. So, i fixed it to be:

```
result = {"metadata"=>{"version"=>5}, "data"=>{"paging"=>{"total_items"=>1, "number_of_pages"=>1}, "items"=>[{"type"=>"OrganizationSummary", "uid"=>"33a97e", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Google"}}]}}
```

Two, you say, you want to remove `data` (removing `metadata` is fine) from it, but the values you need i.e. `uid` and `name`, they are nested inside `data`. So, if you remove it, you will lose those values too.

I guess, you want to remove only `paging` part instead. Here is my solution for this:

```
result.delete('metadata')
 => {"version"=>5}

result['data'].delete('paging')
 => {"total_items"=>1, "number_of_pages"=>1}

# Now the values you need,
# `uid`(s) - can be more than one, as `items` is an array
result['data']['items'].map { |h| h['uid'] }
 => ["33a97e"]

# `name`(s)
result['data']['items'].map { |h| h['properties']['name'] }
 => ["Google"]
```